# How to update the view after routeParams changed in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a designer component which I am loading through routerLink as :

```
<a [routerLink]="['/designer',page._id]">
   <i class="fa fa-eye fa-fw"></i>
</a>
```

when I am redirecting for first time, it successfully gets the routeParams i.e. in my DesignerComponent:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      if (params['id']) {
        this.page_id = params['id'];
        console.log(this.page_id);        
      }
    });
}
```

and after page._id is initialised it fetched page from database & renders the view.

Now I have given routerlink inside designerComponent itself & I am redirecting it using same:

I am able to see page._id logged in console, but my view is not getting updated for new page_id.

I want to change my view if my page is getting changed.

any inputs?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, I need to update my pageObject inside callback only.

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  if (params['id']) {
    this.page_id = params['id'];
    this.getRapidPageFromDb();
    console.log(this.page_id);        
  }
});
```

doing this solved my issue.

thanks